# Python: Checking if a word has more than 3 of the same letters and returning false

Tags: python, duplicates, palindrome

I'm tasked with making a program that finds the longest palindrome in a given text
that doesn't contain more than 3 of the same letters.

```
#This program needs to find the longest palindrome
# that does not contain the same letter more than 3 times

def ispalin(z):
    y = ""
    for i in range(len(z) - 1, -1, -1):
        if z[i] != " ":
            y += z[i]
    if z == y:
        return True
#I'm thinking something needs to be added here, so i can return false
#if the palindrome has more than 3 of the same letter.
    else:
        return False

def haspalin(z, k):
    for i in range(0, len(z) - k + 1):
        if ispalin(z[i:i + k]):
            return (z[i:i + k])
    return False


S = input("Write your text:")
for i in range(len(S), 0, -1):
    z = haspalin(S, i)
    if z:
        print(z)
        break
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the Counter class of the collections module:

```
from collections import Counter

x = "absdasbfna"
print(Counter(x))
```

Output:

```
Counter({'a': 3, 'b': 2, 's': 2, 'd': 1, 'f': 1, 'n': 1})
```

Comment: Ok now i can display the amount of characters in a palindrome.
How can i tell it to return False if it has more than 3 of the same character?
Like

```
if Counter(z) > 3: 
     return False
```

Comment: `not Counter(x)["a"] > 3` That should return the right answer

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you got the text

```py
text = "abc abcb abcba aba xyz"
```

Step 1, split the text in words:
Here the split method of strings will help you.

```py
words = text.split()
```

Step 2, check if a word is a palindrome:
Here you can use the slicing of arrays.

```py
is_palindrome = word == word[-1::-1]
```

Step 3, find the repeating letters:
Here the answer of @CozyCode will help you.

```py
max_repetition = max(Counter(word).values())
```

Step 4, find the longest palindrome, here the `key` argument of `max` could help you:

```py
longest = max(palindromes, key=lambda word: len(word))
```

Now you just need to combine these steps:

```py
from collections import Counter
text = "abc abcb abcba aba xyz cdcdcdcdc"
words = text.split()
palindroms = [word for word in words if word==word[-1::-1]]
allowed_palindroms = [
    palindrom for palindrom in palindroms 
    if max(Counter(palindrom).values()) <= 3
]
longest = max(allowed_palindroms, key=lambda word: len(word))
```